# C++ insertion sort not working for large arrays

Tags: c++, sorting, insertion-sort

my insertionSort function works for small arrays, but does not work for an array with 50,000 random values. I've spent hours trying to figure this out but I'm stumped. Here is the code:

```
void insertionSort(int array[], int length) {
  int swapHolder, counter, index;
  for (counter = 1; counter < length; counter++) {
        index = counter;
        while (counter > 0 && array[index - 1] > array[index]) {
              swapHolder = array[index];
              array[index] = array[index - 1];
              array[index - 1] = swapHolder;
              index--;
        }
    }
}
```

My other sorting function (bubbleSort) works fine for large arrays, but I'm hung up on this issue.

Comment: When you say "does not work", what do you mean by that? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And please  [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: why do you decrement `index` instead of incrementing it O_o

Comment: ... and why are you checking if "counter > 0", because this will always be true? Guaranteed. `counter` is always at least 1, and it is never decremented. The answer to this question is simply: "your insertion sort implementation is wrong".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
while (counter > 0 && array[index - 1] > array[index]) {
```

should be

```
while (index > 0 && array[index - 1] > array[index]) {
```

On a deeper note, the average complexity for insertion sort is `O(n^2)` so that it works best for small arrays. That is, it is not the correct algorithm for sorting 50,000 values.

Comment: Well, neither is BubbleSort. I guess he simply tries to get it right and both should work correctly (albeit slowly) even for large arrays.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. My program is showing it only took 1828 milliseconds to sort 50,000 values.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis This is a class project to show the speeds of various sort/search methods

Comment: Yes, I expected something like that. Thanks for the info.

Comment: The only way to know if it's good for 50000 values is to benchmark on actual data.  If the data is near-sorted, it's a fantastic algorithm.